# Removing item from inner list - linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list **list1**, which contains another list, **list2**.

I have to remove an item from **list2** of **list1**  where id=2 using lambda expression.
How can i write it.?

```
eg: list1 -> List<balls>  -> Ball contains list of images.
    list2 -> List<images> -> each image will have an id.
```

**i need to remove images for some balls from list1(where image id is given as 1)**

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) based on your question?

Comment: Have you tried anything from your side? have you googled for the same?

Comment: yes. i am very new to Linq/Lamda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try with this:

```
list1.ForEach(ball =>
    ball.list2.RemoveAll(image => image.Id == 2));
```

Comment: This sln worked. after removing the image , again i printed all the image id's. it print '2' also. i.e 2 is not removed..right.?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
list1.First(k => k.id == 2)
     .list2.RemoveAt(0);
```

If your id refers to list2, you have to make loop.

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    item.list2.RemoveAll(k => k.id == 2);
}
```

Or alternatively,

```
list1.ForEach(item => item.list2.RemoveAll(k => k.id == 2));
```

Comment: `Id` is for `image`, not `ball`

Comment: id is given for images. i.e for list2 object